# Javascript Outline in Eclipse Neon - Java EE IDE

Tags: javascript, eclipse, prototype, eclipse-neon

I've just updated my Eclipse from Mars to Neon. 
The Outline content for js files is now broken : it does not display my object class members but only class names. This is the way I'm declaring my "objects" :

```
function ClappingOption(){
'use strict';

if(ClappingOption.initialized === undefined) {

ClappingOption.prototype.setHtml = function (jqSelector) {
    console.log('hello');
});

ClappingOption.initialized=true;
}

}
```

Is there an option/plug-in to activate outline for this style of coding? or should I rewrite my code ?

EDIT1 : I could add support of this style with Webclipse. But no more with th CodeMix paying update ;-( that broke again the outlook.

EDIT2 : with later release like Eclipse 2019-06 Javascript and Web developper the support is back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Neon the JavaScript tooling was almost created from scratch again. I assume the broken Outline view for ES5 will be fixed in an upcoming version. Currently, if you use [ES6 (ECMAScript 2015)](http://es6-features.org/#ClassDefinition) the Outline view will work as expected:

```
'use strict';
class ClappingOption {
  setHtml(jqSelector) {
    console.log('hello');
  };
}
```

Comment: The problem is that some browsers still in use do not support class. How do you circumvent this?

Comment: @frank, I have not yet tested it, but maybe I would use an [ES6-to-ES5 compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code='use%20strict'%3B%0D%0Aclass%20ClappingOption%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20setHtml(jqSelector)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('hello')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D).